# How to save openCV cv::Mat to an image without alterations

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, libtiff

I've seen other questions attempting to answer this ( in a method similar to [mkuse's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848658/opencv-c-how-to-save-a-16bit-image?noredirect=1&lq=1)  using FileStorage ). But it seems as though the ONLY way to do this is by saving it to .xml or .yml

I really need a way to save a file using imwrite() that doesn't cut off all my 16bit decimal values.

I really wanted to do it in a .tif but [it seems that I can't do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154548/saving-frames-in-opencv-without-compression?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There HAS to be another way!

Comment: you could convert to 16 bit integer range or code as 16 bit integer and save a png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try saving it using something other than `imwrite`. If you write your image data in a binary file using `fstream` as shown in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061122/write-a-table-of-doubles-to-binary-file-io-c), you wouldn't lose any precision. It just makes the saving and reading process a bit more complicated but you could easily write wrappers for that.

Such as is being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577060/whats-the-most-basic-way-to-format-a-2d-matrix-of-doubles-in-binary-for-reading).

Comment: Thanks @Sunreef !! I actually was just deciding to go ahead and do that yesterday as I was leaving work. I just wanted to make double sure that I needed to write some wrappers and that I didn't miss something obvious.