# What's the most basic way to format a 2D matrix of doubles in binary for reading into IDL?

Tags: c++, matrix, binary, idl-programming-language

So I have an i by j matrix of doubles in C++ that I want to read into an IDL program.

Lets say that the matrix is called data, with size ROWS by COLS, and name string saved to filename. And I just write the values out in a stream to a binary file.

```
ofstream myfile (filename, ios::binary);
if(myfile.isopen())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
     for (int j=0; j < COLS; j++){
          myfile<<data.at(i,j);
}
myfile.close();
```

I then want to read it back into IDL but I'm new to working with binary in IDL and following the documentation has gotten me here but it's not working.

```
function read_binmatrix, filename, ROWS, COLS, thetype

    mat = READ_BINARY(filename,DATA_TYPE=thetype,DATA_DIMS=[ROWS-1,COLS-1])
    return, mat

end
 ...
 ...
matrix = read_binmatrix(file2,num_rows,num_cols,5)
```

...but I get this error as output.

```
% READ_BINARY: READU: End of file encountered. Unit: 100, File:
...
% Execution halted at: READ_BINMATRIX     21 
...
```

Comment: have you tested the C++ portion stand-alone, as well as viewed the binary file to validate the values you are expected are there?

Comment: Are you sure this question is tagged correctly with [tag:idl]?

Comment: *IDL, short for Interface Description Language, is a language [...] **(Not to be confused with [tag:idl-programming-language], a language used for scientific and and medical image analysis)*** - Are you using the correct `[idl]` tag?

Comment: `myfile<<data.at(i,j);` writes text to the file, not binary data. To write binary format use `std::ofstream::write()`.

Comment: Edited: Changed tag to idl-programming-language, (that's really confusing)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't give you credit for a correct answer if you write the correct answer in a comment :) thanks though ;) ...should I write the answer or do you want it? That was totally it. I'm sure I'm not that first person to forget and do this wrong.

Comment: @JeremyGamet Well, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 myfile<<data.at(i,j);
```

writes text to the file, not binary data. To write the numbers in binary format use [`std::ofstream::write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
 myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data.at(i,j),sizeof(decltype(data.at(i,j))));
```